# Alignment of nested SVG's

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to achieve a layout of several SVG's as illustrated below.

[image]

The gray box is the top-level SVG containing the other elements. The width and height is known.
The orange boxes contain the red boxes and need to retain the same distance from each other. Similar to how `justify-content: space-around` aligns items.

The red boxes also retain their distance in the same way (but vertically).

---

I've been trying to adjust the positioning with `transform-origin` but it does not seem to work. Instead the offset is always calculated from the top-left of each element, which pushes the elements out of view. This is a very basic snippet, but it's all I have sadly.

```html
<svg width="400" height="400" style="background:#ccc;">
  <g transform="translate(10, 10)">
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(200, 10)">
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(360, 10)">
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>
    <svg width="50" height="50">
      <rect width="50" height="50" fill="red" />
    </svg>
  </g>
</svg>
```

---

Is there a way to align these containers this way **without knowing** the size of the red boxes?
Every solution I end up with uses some calculation where I would need to subtract half the width and height of the red boxes.

Comment: Instead of using all those nested svg elements you can put a rect in the defs. the rect would be centered around the point 0,0 something like `<rect id="rect" width="50" height="50" fill="red" x="-25" y="-25" />` Next you can use the rect with <use> where the x and y attributes are defining the position of the use element

Comment: @enxaneta I'll try that. But will it help with the alignment also?

Comment: you need to choose the points for the grid and <use> the rect in those points

Comment: Do you need to target the individual red squares and change them?

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman no. They are actually other imported SVG images that are of varied sizes. I added red squares in this post for simplicity's sake. Basically what I am trying to say is that I don't know the exact size nor aspect ratio beforehand as they are different images each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in a comment **@enxaneta** :

> Instead of using all those nested svg elements you can put a rect in
> the defs. the rect would be centered around the point 0,0

In SVG, element positions are relative to the top left corner of the canvas.
If you specify the same `x=40` coordinates for several rectangles, then they will be vertically aligned.
In order not to write for each rectangle the values of its coordinates, as well as the values of `width` and `height`, you need to place one instance in the `<defs>` section and then clone it using the `<use>` tag.

In this case, you need to specify the coordinates `x`,`y` for each copy:

`<use xlink:href="#rect" x="40" y="62.5" />`

To get three columns you need to wrap one column in a `<g>` group tag and clone it with `<use>`

`<use xlink:href="#column" x="150" y="0" />`

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
         width="450" height="400" viewBox="0 0 450 400"    style="background:#ccc;">
 <defs>
  <rect id="rect" width="50" height="50" fill="red" x="0" y="0" /> 
 </defs> 
 
<g id="column" > 
 <rect x="30" y="0" width="70" height="400" fill="#C89F33" />
   <use xlink:href="#rect" x="40" y="62.5" /> 
    <use xlink:href="#rect" x="40" y="175" />
      <use xlink:href="#rect" x="40" y="287.5" /> 
</g> 
  <use xlink:href="#column" x="150" y="0" />
    <use xlink:href="#column" x="300" y="0" />  
       
 </svg>
```